# Is there a way to distinguish time selection events from calendar events in onChange event for `flatpickr`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flatpickr

I couldn't find a way to distinguish time selection events from calendar events in `flatpickr` when `onChange` event being triggered.

```
const instance = flatpickr(flatpickrRef.current, {
   mode: 'range',
   enableTime: true,
   time_24hr: true,
   defaultDate: defaultDate as unknown as number,
   disable: [
     date => {
       return date > new Date();
     },
   ],
   positionElement: positionElementRef.current,
   onClose,
   onChange,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`mousedown` event gets fired when **date** is selected or else **time** is changed

```js
const instance = flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
  mode: 'range',
  enableTime: true,
  time_24hr: true,
  disable: [
    date => {
      return date > new Date();
    },
  ],
  onChange: () => {
    console.log(event ? 'Date Changed' : 'Time Changed')
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<div class="flatpickr">
  <input name="test" value="03.07.2019" type="text" data-input>
  <a class="input-button" title="toggle" data-toggle>
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```